# Is there a way to hide printing base class properties when doing derived_class_obj.sprint();

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

Here is an example.

```
class A1 extends uvm_object;
  int z;
  ...
endclass

class B1 extends A1;
  ...
endclass

class C1 extends A1;
B1 b_obj;
  ...
endclass
```

Now from some uvm_component, `C1 c_obj = new(); ... c_obj.sprint();` prints int z twice as C1 extends from A1 and has a member object of B1 class which also extends from A1.

Is there a way to suppress printing members of base class when called `derived_class.sprint()` ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: declare it as `local` and then check.

Comment: Are you calling b_obj.sprint() in C1's sprint function?

Answer (score 0):

We can do conditional printing by keeping different variables in all class and in respective class do_print method use that variable to print variable.